# Network Daughter Card vs Network Interface Card

Tags: interface, terminology

I've noticed that when customizing a server for Dell you have the option to select between "Network Daughter Cards" and "Network Interface Cards", as well as a number of others. I've looked up the term 'daughter card', but it seems like the two previous terms (NDC and NIC) both fall under that definition. I've also looked for comparisons or differentiators between the two but can't find anything that would justify there being two different terms.

Does anyone know the difference between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A daughter card is typically something used in a blade chassis. But it can also apply to proprietary or internal interfaces within a system -- most commonly for RAID hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Network Daughter Card or NDC are by default feature on the MotherBoard. That could be 1G or 10G. 
NIC are additional network cards, such as from Intel 10G  SFP+ or Base-T copper, Broadcom, QLogic, SolarFlare, Mellanox cards which sits on the PCIe slots.